# In cron, /usr/bin/paplay does not display stderr

Tags: cron, file-descriptors, stderr

My PC's pulse audio dies whenever I open and close virtualbox windows in a certain situation.

So I tried to monitor the audio state by crontab -e.

Usually, in the commandline, `` $ paplay beep.wav >>err.log 2>&1 || echo "`\`date\` `" >>err.log; ``   is enough. 
If no error, it adds nothing to err.log but beeping sound. 
If an error, it adds "... shm_open() ..." and a current timestamp to err.log  without beeping sound.

But if I locate this command line in cron, it makes beep sound periodically but when failed it does not log err.log. It simply doesn't make any stderr though no beep sounds. Likewise, `|| echo...` doesn't work, either.

Comment: Please post your `crontab -l` entry for this command.

Comment: @yahol , after rebooting everything works fine, thouse sound problem still persists.

Comment: How about enclosing that whole script in a file and adding the script to cron?

Comment: @yahol , Thanks for ur info. Everything works fine without adding external script. Audio problem can be reproduced by deleting any of `pulse-shm-2780269722` looking files in /dev/shm/ .